# How to get only rows that match some criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

| Name | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Leo | 89 | 12 | 32 |
| Ann | 20 | 85 | 10 |
| Joanne | 10 | 20 | 50 |
| Joaquin | 20 | 30 | 40 |

How to get only the rows with Score1, Score2 and Score3 >= 85?

I want a fast method, since there could be more than 3 columns as a score and I need a way to filter all of these columns and get only the rows when any of these scores >= 85.

The output should be:

| Name | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Leo | 89 | 12 | 32 |
| Ann | 20 | 85 | 10 |

I also want to know a better approach when the Score column number is variable (we could have 10 score columns instead of 3, so it will be weird to put 10 filters)

Comment: Rather `df[df.filter(like='Score').ge(85).any(1)]` ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your case

```
out = df[df.filter(like = 'Score').ge(85).any(1)]
Out[54]: 
  Name  Score1  Score2  Score3
0  Leo      89      12      32
1  Ann      20      85      10
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add this code

```
_filter = df.filter(like='Score').ge(85).any(1)
print(df[_filter])
```